# ModuleNotFoundError at /auth/users/me/ No module named 'accounts'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, postman, djoser

I am using djoser and django-rest-framework JWT for user authentication . According to doc.[for djaoser](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/base_endpoints.html#base-endpoints) . I have `/user/` end point for creating a user and `/user/me/` for getting details. The first endponts works fine but in the second `/user/me/` , it give me the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError at /auth/users/me/

No module named 'accounts'
```

I don't know where the problem lies. I am testing it on postman.

here is my settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from django.conf import settings
from datetime import timedelta
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-jyhhr)v0kyrb+^ifdlio=p3mo&l=$(^an7xb&fow--z^rxd7^r'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    'djoser',
    'base.apps.BaseConfig',

    'corsheaders',
    'social_django'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',

    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]
import os
ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'frontend/build')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '94.mbbs.2@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'hfbuehwaolnzujut'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True


DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': False,
    'USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SET_USERNAME_RETYPE': True,
    'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'email/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SOCIAL_AUTH_TOKEN_STRATEGY': 'djoser.social.token.jwt.TokenStrategy',
    'SOCIAL_AUTH_ALLOWED_REDIRECT_URIS': ['http://127.0.0.1:8000/google', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/facebook'],

    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'base.serializers.UserSerializer',
        'user': 'base.serializers.UserSerializer',
        'current_user': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user_delete': 'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer',
    }
}

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = '334707760983-00fuqjm5140bme0ro7r6kkujfg1feo2s.apps.googleusercontent.com'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET = 'Lqe_6O7WTUvZL0bRfTtBMHcn'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
                                   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', 'openid']
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_EXTRA_DATA = ['first_name', 'last_name']

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ('rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser', 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', ),

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (

        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    )

}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    # 'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
)
SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=30),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),

    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),


    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': ('rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',),

}
# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'


CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
MEDIA_ROOT = "static/images"

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
    BASE_DIR /  'frontend/build/static'
]
```

I am using Django's built in user and not any custom user with a little bit modification.
If yuo wanna see , here it is:
in *myenv>lib>site-packages>django>contrib>auth>models.py*

```
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    An abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with
    admin-compliant permissions.

    Username and password are required. Other fields are optional.
    """
    username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

    username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=150, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=150, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), blank=True , unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _('staff status'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
            'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
        ),
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)

    objects = UserManager()

    # EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    # REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name','last_name']

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('user')
        verbose_name_plural = _('users')
        abstract = True

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        self.email = self.__class__.objects.normalize_email(self.email)

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Return the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        """
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        """Return the short name for the user."""
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        """Send an email to this user."""
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

**What I have checked so far**

Most of solutons on the internet suggest to add accounts in settings.py INSTALLED_APPS but I have not created any accounts app so there is no reason to add it. I will be highly thankful to you if you can help because it has wasted a lot of my time. Thanks
❤️❤️❤️

Answer (score 1):

if you read the doc carefully at [SERIALIZERS-note](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html#serializers)
here is the clue

> Key 'user' is used for general users whereas 'current_user' lets you set serializer for special /users/me endpoint. They both default to the same serializer though.

so if you look at the DJOSER SERIALIZERS in setings.py

```
'SERIALIZERS': {
    'user_create': 'base.serializers.UserSerializer',
    'user': 'base.serializers.UserSerializer',
    'current_user': 'account.serializers.UserCreateSerializer', #here is the problem. What is 'account' doing here. You should cmoment this
    'user_delete': 'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer',
}
```